# How do I make sure this ajax call only happens when a user interacts with it, not on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

In my `app/assets/javascripts/profiles.js`, I have the following:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {    
  var sliders = $('.slider');
  var buttons = $('.slider-step-value');

  for ( var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++ ) {
    var button = $(sliders[i]).prev('p').find('button')[0];
    var _slider_type = sliders[i].id.split('-')[1];
    var _original_value = $('button#' + button.id).data(_slider_type + "-value");
    noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
      start: _original_value,
      step: 1,
      behaviour: 'tap',
      connect: [true, false],
      range: {
        'min':  1,
        'max':  10
      }
    });

    attachEvent(sliders[i], button);
  }

  function attachEvent(slider,button){
    slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
      button.innerText = parseInt(values[handle]);
      var _profile_id = button.id.split('-').slice(4).join('-');
      var _rating_type = button.id.split('-')[3]
      var url = "/profiles/" + _profile_id + "/" + _rating_type + "_rating/?" + _rating_type + "=" + button.innerText

      $.ajax({
        type: "PATCH",
        url: url,
        success: function(){
          // console.log(_profile_id + "'s " + _rating_type + " was successfully updated.");
        },
        error: function(){
          // console.log(_profile_id + "'s " + _rating_type + " was NOT successfully updated.");
        }
      })
    });
  }
});
```

What happens when I reload any `Profile#Show` page, this is what the log looks like:

```
Started PATCH "/profiles/rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college/speed_rating/?speed=7" for ::1 at 2016-10-31 14:51:56 -0500
Processing by ProfilesController#speed_rating as */*
Started PATCH "/profiles/rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college/tackling_rating/?tackling=9" for ::1 at 2016-10-31 14:51:56 -0500
Processing by ProfilesController#tackling_rating as */*
  Parameters: {"tackling"=>"9", "id"=>"rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college"}
Started PATCH "/profiles/rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college/passing_rating/?passing=7" for ::1 at 2016-10-31 14:51:56 -0500
Started PATCH "/profiles/rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college/dribbling_rating/?dribbling=4" for ::1 at 2016-10-31 14:51:56 -0500
  Parameters: {"speed"=>"7", "id"=>"rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college"}
Processing by ProfilesController#passing_rating as */*
  Parameters: {"passing"=>"7", "id"=>"rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college"}
  Profile Load (5.6ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."slug" = $1 ORDER BY "profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["slug", "rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Processing by ProfilesController#dribbling_rating as */*
  Parameters: {"dribbling"=>"4", "id"=>"rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college"}
  Profile Load (53.0ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."slug" = $1 ORDER BY "profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["slug", "rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Profile Load (54.2ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."slug" = $1 ORDER BY "profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["slug", "rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Grade Load (9.0ms)  SELECT "grades".* FROM "grades" WHERE "grades"."profile_id" = 7
  Profile Load (5.4ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."slug" = $1 ORDER BY "profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["slug", "rebecca-nitzsche-st-george-s-college"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Grade Load (5.9ms)  SELECT "grades".* FROM "grades" WHERE "grades"."profile_id" = 7
  Grade Load (13.2ms)  SELECT "grades".* FROM "grades" WHERE "grades"."profile_id" = 7
  HABTM_Positions Load (14.7ms)  SELECT "positions_profiles".* FROM "positions_profiles" WHERE "positions_profiles"."profile_id" = 7
  Grade Load (13.5ms)  SELECT "grades".* FROM "grades" WHERE "grades"."profile_id" = 7
  HABTM_Positions Load (12.2ms)  SELECT "positions_profiles".* FROM "positions_profiles" WHERE "positions_profiles"."profile_id" = 7
  HABTM_Positions Load (147.3ms)  SELECT "positions_profiles".* FROM "positions_profiles" WHERE "positions_profiles"."profile_id" = 7
  Position Load (4.3ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" WHERE "positions"."id" = 7
  Position Load (6.2ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" WHERE "positions"."id" = 7
  HABTM_Positions Load (14.8ms)  SELECT "positions_profiles".* FROM "positions_profiles" WHERE "positions_profiles"."profile_id" = 7
  Position Load (9.1ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" WHERE "positions"."id" = 7
  Achievement Load (3.5ms)  SELECT "achievements".* FROM "achievements" WHERE "achievements"."profile_id" = 7
  Achievement Load (89.6ms)  SELECT "achievements".* FROM "achievements" WHERE "achievements"."profile_id" = 7
  Position Load (83.1ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" WHERE "positions"."id" = 7
  Achievement Load (6.0ms)  SELECT "achievements".* FROM "achievements" WHERE "achievements"."profile_id" = 7
  Video Load (5.0ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."profile_id" = 7
  Video Load (10.8ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."profile_id" = 7
  Achievement Load (12.9ms)  SELECT "achievements".* FROM "achievements" WHERE "achievements"."profile_id" = 7
  Video Load (98.2ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."profile_id" = 7
  Transcript Load (10.2ms)  SELECT "transcripts".* FROM "transcripts" WHERE "transcripts"."profile_id" = 7
  Transcript Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "transcripts".* FROM "transcripts" WHERE "transcripts"."profile_id" = 7
  Video Load (6.6ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."profile_id" = 7
  Transcript Load (5.7ms)  SELECT "transcripts".* FROM "transcripts" WHERE "transcripts"."profile_id" = 7
  User Load (4.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (8.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Transcript Load (35.1ms)  SELECT "transcripts".* FROM "transcripts" WHERE "transcripts"."profile_id" = 7
  User Load (35.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rating Load (5.4ms)  SELECT  "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."user_id" = 7 AND "ratings"."profile_id" = 7 LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rating Load (5.4ms)  SELECT  "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."user_id" = 7 AND "ratings"."profile_id" = 7 LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (5.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rating Load (18.2ms)  SELECT  "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."user_id" = 7 AND "ratings"."profile_id" = 7 LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (20.2ms)  BEGIN
   (4.4ms)  BEGIN
  Rating Load (10.4ms)  SELECT  "ratings".* FROM "ratings" WHERE "ratings"."user_id" = 7 AND "ratings"."profile_id" = 7 LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (10.9ms)  BEGIN
   (7.1ms)  COMMIT
   (4.9ms)  BEGIN
   (45.6ms)  COMMIT
   (42.7ms)  COMMIT
   (379.0ms)  COMMIT
No template found for ProfilesController#tackling_rating, rendering head :no_content
No template found for ProfilesController#speed_rating, rendering head :no_content
No template found for ProfilesController#passing_rating, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 2224ms (ActiveRecord: 90.0ms)


Completed 204 No Content in 2312ms (ActiveRecord: 440.7ms)


No template found for ProfilesController#dribbling_rating, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 2311ms (ActiveRecord: 244.2ms)


Completed 204 No Content in 2271ms (ActiveRecord: 571.3ms)
```

I believe the bulk of those calls are coming from my `set_profile` method:

```
before_action :set_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :invite_user, :speed_rating, :tackling_rating, :dribbling_rating, :passing_rating, :profiles]

def set_profile
  @profile = Profile.includes(:grades, :positions, :achievements, :videos, :transcripts).friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

So all I need to be able to do is the following:

1. How do I make sure that the `$.ajax` call, only happens when a user interacts with the slider, not necessarily on first page load. **Note** that the `slider` needs to be updated on the first page load because it needs to set the `start` value to the `_original_value` as you can see in the `noUiSlider.create` call.

Once I can figure that out, I believe most of those DB calls on the initial page load should disappear and my page load time should improve significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use another event like slide or change:  https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/

Or could it be that your create code is fireing the update event?

Comment: Dude....that's brilliant. Simply changing the event from `update` to `slide` is exactly what fixed it for me. Thanks much!

Comment: But now that this is working, this reveals another bug with the way it is setup which is that it submits the result to the DB after every `step` move. So for instance, say I want to move from a rating of `4` to `10`, it submits the rating at `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, and then `10`. This is causing an issue because if the DB update gets interrupted, by say using another slider while it is being updated in the bg, the true setting doesn't get recorded. If I create another question, you think you can look into it for me?

Comment: Actually...nevermind, I figured it out. Your link helped again. I just used `set` instead of `slide`. Thanks again!